# Italics for the title of my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am using a BibTeX style bibliography and would like the "Bibliography" heading to be italicized. I managed to italicize it in the table of contents but not in the main text by doing:

```
\bibliography{bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\emph{Bibliography}}
```

Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: It's ok, I actually found how to do it :)

Comment: which documentclass you are using?